# How to change Key of an object dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object like this:

```
var obj{};
```

I want to set object values dynamically like so:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
quest='quest'+i;
header='header'+i;
$(obj).data(quest,{header:i});
quest,header=0;
}
```

I'm expecting object to be saved like:

```
obj{quest1:{header1:1},
quest2:{header2:2}
quest3:{header3:3}
```

But they are saved like:

```
obj{quest1:{header:1},
quest2:{header:2},
quest3:{header:3},
```

The header-key in my object is not getting the actual value. but simply save as "header"..

Could you please guide me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
var obj = {};

for(i=1; i<11; i++) {
   quest='quest'+i;
   header='header'+i;
   obj[quest] = {};
   obj[quest][header] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code your loop starts with `i = 0` but the properties start by 1.

```
var quest, header, obj = {};

for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  quest = 'quest' + (i + 1);
  header = 'header' + (i + 1);
  obj[quest] = {};
  obj[quest][header] = (i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a variable key in an object literal.